# Excel / VBscript: Need to sort columns with a header

Tags: vbscript, microsoft-excel, sorting, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a vbsctipt that opens an Excel(2007) document copies the used range from two sheets (minus the header on sheet 2) puts it all on 3rd sheet. I then need to sort that data using the header. I have the values of the range I need to sort in a vairable already. I just don't know the sytax to get Excel to sort it based on the data in Column A.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you're looking for.

http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1243616&page=1